# Delete rows in database that are outside an subject_id specific date range

Tags: sql, database, datetime, google-bigquery

I have a problem regarding the table, shown in this picture:

[Picture of the Table]

[image: 1]

For my problem, it is enough, to only consider the columns "subject_id" and "starttime". The table does have about 5.000 unique subject_id's. Every subject_id can have multiple rows, with different starttimes. For each subject_id, i want to **delete** every row, with the following condition:

```
WHERE starttime IS NOT BETWEEN  MIN(starttime) AND date_add(MIN(starttime), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

with MIN(starttime) being the earliest date in column "starttime", individually for every subject_id.

I can't figure out a way on how to tackle this problem. I thought that maybe one could somehow solve the problem using PARTITION BY, but i have not found a way to delete rows in PARTITION BY context.

Comment: please tag your database as well. also "database partitioning" is totally another subject

Comment: What do you mean by "tag your database"? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

here is one way :

```
delete from yourtable t1
where t1.starttime > (
        select date_add(MIN(starttime), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
        from yourtable t2
        where t1.subject_id = t2.subject_id
    )
```

Comment: That was super helpful, thanks! Since I work with Google Biq Query, this Code doesn't work for me (i'm not sure why, but it does not work). But I used your Code to write a Query that worked for me.

Comment: @mika_d98 that’s why you should tag your database in your questions, anyways what do you mean by it didn’t work? You got an error? Also up it accept the answer if it it helped thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
SELECT *
FROM ds1
WHERE ds1.starttime <= (
    SELECT date_add(MIN(starttime), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
    FROM ds1 ds1_temp
    WHERE ds1.subject_id = ds1_temp.subject_id
)
```

it doesn't delete the rows, but it creates a new table, which is fine for me. Thanks a lot!